# Polimorfismo com ArrayList

Tags: java, array

Tenho a Iinterface abaixo e gostaria de saber como faço para sobrepor o método passando outro objeto para `List` pois possuo 4 classes na minha entidade, por exemplo as classes da entidade são `cliente`, `colaborador`, `produto` e `serviço` e as classes que implementam a interface são `ClienteDAO`, `ColaboradorDAO`, `ServicoDAO`, `ProdutoDAO` segue abaixo também um exemplo dessas:

```
public interface ISalaoDAO {

    int save(Object object);
    int update(Object object);
    int remove(Long id);
     List<Cliente> findAll();

}
```

---

```
public class ClienteDAO implements ISalaoDAO{
private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL = 
            "select * from CLIENTE";
public List<Cliente> findAll() {
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            pstm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_ALL);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.setId(rs.getLong("ID_CLIENTE"));
                cliente.setCliente(rs.getString("NOME_CLIENTE"));
                cliente.setEnderecoCliente(rs.getString("ENDERECO_CLIENTE"));
                cliente.setTelefoneCliente(rs.getString("TELEFONE_CLIENTE"));
                clientes.add(cliente);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            try{
                if(conn != null){
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }catch(SQLException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }finally{
                DBConnection.close(conn, pstm, rs);
            }                   
        }   
        return clientes;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nunca tentei fazer e não sei se viola o princípio de substituição de Liskov ou algo assim, mas sugiro o seguinte:

```
public interface ISalaoDAO<T> {
    int save(T object);
    int update(T object);
    int remove(Long id);
    List<T> findAll();
}
```

Aí você especifica o tipo de T na classe implementadora:

```
public class ClienteDAO implements ISalaoDAO<Cliente> {
    ...
    public List<Cliente> findAll() {
        ...
    }
}
```